# Taylor series in algebraic geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $F\in k[T_1,\ldots, T_N]$ be a non-zero polynomial and take $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_N) \in \mathbb A^N$. Then $F$ has an expression in *Taylor series in $x$*

$$F(T)=F^{(0)}(T)+F^{(1)}(T)+\cdots +F^{(r)}(T).$$

The differential in $x$ is defined as

$$d_xF=F^{(1)}(T).$$

Then, we have

$$d_xF=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial F}{\partial T_i}(x)(T_i-x_i).$$

**Example**

Let $F=T_1^3-T_2^2$ and $x=(1,1)$, writing $F=F^{(0)}+F^{(1)}+F^{(2)}+F^{(3)}$, where $F^{(j)}$ is the homogeneous component of degree $j$ in the variables $T_1-1$ and $T_2-1$, we have

$$F^{(0)}=0$$
$$F^{(1)}=d_xF=3(T_1-1)-2(T_2-1)$$
$$F^{(2)}=3(T_1-1)^2-(T_2-1)^2$$
$$F^{(3)}=(T_1-1)^3$$

I didn't understand how we can find the $F^{(i)}, i\neq 1$.

The book I'm using only mention how to find $F^{(1)}$.

I need help.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Following the comments $k$ is an algebraically closed field, $\mathbb A^n$ is the usual notation for the set $(x_1,…,x_n)$, where $x_i \in k$ and $T_i$ are the indeterminates over $k$.

Comment: You should clarify the notation. What is $k$, are $T_i$ algebraically independent, what is $\mathbb A$, what is $\mathbb A^N$?

Comment: @Ivan k is an algebraically closed field, $\mathbb A^n$ is the usual notation for the set $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where $x_i\in k$, $T_i$ are the indeterminates of $F$

Comment: @YACP I'm going to review again the answers I've got, I will see what I can do. Thank you for the remark

Comment: @YACP is it ok now?

Comment: I’m still not sure what $\mathbb A^n$ is. Is it the same as $k^n$?

Comment: @ivan yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to write the polynomial $F$ in terms of $T_1-1$ and $T_2-1$. You have

\begin{eqnarray}T_1^3-T_2^2 & = & (T_1-1+1)^3 - (T_2-1+1)^2 \\ & = & (T_1-1)^3 + 3(T_1-1)^2 + 3(T_1-1) + 1 - (T_2-1)^2+(T_2-1)+1\end{eqnarray}

so for example $$F^{(2)} = 3(T_1-1)^2 - (T_2-1)^2.$$

There is also a formula generalizing the one you write. If we define a differential operator of degree $i$ by

$$D^{(i)} = \sum_I {(i_1, \dots, i_N)!}T_1^{i_1} \dots T_N^{i_N}  \frac{\partial^{i_1}}{\partial T_{1}^{i_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial^{i_N}}{\partial T_{N}^{i_N}} ,$$

where the sum runs over the multi-indices $I = (i_1, \dots, i_N)$ of non-negative integers such that $i_1 + \dots + i_N = i$, and  ${(i_1, \dots, i_N)!}$ is the multinomial coefficient $\frac{(i_1+ \dots + i_N)!}{i_1! \cdots i_N!}$. Then

$$F^{(i)} = \frac{D^{(i)} F}{i!}.$$

Comment: There are some minor mistakes, but I understood the whole picture, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The higher order terms of the Taylor expansion are given by $$F^{(r)}(T) = \sum \frac{1}{d_1! d_2! \ldots d_N!}(\partial_{d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_N} F)(x) (T_1-x_1)^{d_1}(T_2-x_2)^{d_2}\ldots(T_N-x_N)^{d_N}$$ where the sum ranges over all sequences of nonnegative integers such that $d_1 + d_2 + \ldots + d_N = r$.  The notation $\partial_{d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_N} F$ means to differentiate $F$ $d_1$ times with respect to $T_1$ , then $d_2$ times respect to $T_2$, $\ldots$, then $d_N$ times with respect to $T_N$.

To see that this is correct, first check it for the case where all $x_i = 0$.  Then it's easy to see that the term of the Taylor series corresponding to $(d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_N)$ is just the same as the term in $F$ with the monomial $T_1^{d_1} T_2^{d_2} \ldots T_N^{d_N}$.  For the general case, make a linear change of variable to reduce to the case where $x_i = 0$.